# An issue with QFile class nesting

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qvector, qtextstream

The problem occurs when I define a struct like the following one

```
struct TInputData
{
    QString      filename;
    QFile        file;
    QTextStream  stream;
};
```

then I put this into a QVector container as follows:

```
QVector<struct TInputData> input(DATA_SOURCE_END);
```

after that I invoke some methods of the vector member fields:

```
for(int i = 0; i < DATA_SOURCE_END; ++i)
{
    input[i].filename = QString(argv[i + 1]);
    input[i].file.setFileName(input[i].filename);
    if (!input[i].file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QDebug(QtCriticalMsg) << "Failed to open input file: " << input[i].filename << "!!!";
        return a.exec();
    }
    input[i].stream.setDevice(&input[i].file);
    qDebug() << "Connected to input file " << input[i].filename;
}
```

I am getting the following compilation error:

```
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qfile.h:209: error: 'QFile::QFile(const QFile&)' is private 
within this context <at line where struct TInputData is declared>
```

And just the same regarding QTextStream.

So what am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE**

The solution offered by @Ashot is to manually create TInputData objects. But it introduces some additional memory management difficulties. The workaround is smart pointers usage.

Comment: It means that `QFile` objects are not copyable, which obviously makes them hard to put in a vector. You could use pointers if you are prepared to manage the memory. Some kind of smart pointer would be the easiest answer.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to play with `TInputData` pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `QVector<struct TInputData> input(DATA_SOURCE_END);` to `QVector<TInputData*> input(DATA_SOURCE_END);`

`QVector` need to copy of its content, but copy constructor of `QFile` is private, it cant be copied.

When using pointers you should manually new and delete your TInputData objects or you can use smart pointers for it.

You can try `QSharedPointer` http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsharedpointer.html#QSharedPointer-2.
Your vector will be `QVector<QSharedPointer<TInputData> > input(DATA_SOURCE_END)`

Comment: thanks a lot! Could you please recommend some info (probably with usage examples) to read about smart pointers?